# Either or select in a single sql query

Tags: mysql, sql

I am beginner in sql world and hope I manged to put the question statement correctly.
Ok my question is how to create a mutual exclusive mysql query where the results are based on the condition.
For example : table 
emp

```
----------
id   name
---------
1    tom
2    dik
3    harry
4    mike
5    john
```

if ask for "john" select should give ONLY record of john , if john not found then give all remaining records.

I am struggling to imagining how the exclusivity will be work. 
My tries are :

---

```
select case 
when if exists select 1 from emp where emp_name = 'john'
then select emp_name from emp where emp_name = 'john'
else select emp_name from emp
end;
```

---

```
SELECT COALESCE(select emp_name from emp where emp_name = 'john',select emp_name from emp)
```

---

```
select distinct(e.emp_name) from emp e left outer join emp f where e.emp_name = 'john' OR e.emp_name = f.emp_name;
```

---

ofcourse none of them are working..
My questions
 : How to approach such queries?
 : Can we build if-then in sqls? will work row by row or on filtered results?
 : If this is already answered anywhere, would be more than happy to have the link.

Comment: What does "all remaining records" mean?  Get all records?

Comment: @jalal try creating stored procedure, and you will write 2 simple select queries in this stored procedure. first, check how many records exist for John, then condition if records exist then return records otherwise another select query to return all records.

Comment: @ysth, it means records which are not 'john'...

Comment: @KlwntSingh, i was thinking without stored procedure... as using PL will definitely simpify things...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this:

```
select emp_name
from emp
where emp_name = 'john'
union all
select emp_name
from emp
where not exists (select 1 from emp where emp_name = 'john');
```

Comment: I don't think you need the `emp_name <> 'john' and`; if the not exists is true that will always be true

Comment: Thanks Gordon, you save my life !!! excellent solution...want to know , is it a proper way to approach mutual exclusive queries..?? (queries where "either or" is required)

Answer (score 0):

```
select e.emp_name
from emp e
left join emp emp_john on emp_john.emp_name='john'
where emp_john.emp_name is null or e.emp_name='john'
```